# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^nx^n$ diverges for $x \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> Show that the series
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^nx^n$$
>   diverges for $x \neq 0$.

Any help? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Is that what you intended? By the way, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant! I was just reading on how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *[power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)* whose [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Radius_of_convergence) $R$ is $0$:

So the root test is certainly appropriate:

$$\frac 1{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[\large n]{n^n}} = \frac {1}{\lim_{n\to \infty} n} = 0$$

> Since the radius of convergence is $0$, the series diverges for any $x\,$ such that $ \;|x| > 0$.
>   I.e., the series diverges $\forall x \neq 0$.

Comment: That is what he's trying to prove, really.

Comment: I used the root test.. and that showed me it converges at zero. But I don't understand how that shows it diverges when n is not zero.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $x\neq 0$. Let $u_n=n^nx^n$. Show that $u_n\not\to 0$.

Comment: Could I use the ratio test after that?

Comment: @ryan The root test is much more apropriate. However, what I'm telling you is much simpler. If $u_n \not\to 0$, $\sum u_n$ fails to exist.

Comment: Could you explain this more in depth? I'm not understanding why.

Comment: @RyanDawkins: In general, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to 0$. The converse needn't hold (consider the harmonic series), but a good way to show that some series fail to converge is to show that their summands don't tend to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (xn)^n \geq \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{x} \rceil}^{\infty} (xn)^n \geq \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{x} \rceil}^{\infty} (x\lceil \frac{1}{x} \rceil)^n \geq \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{x} \rceil}^{\infty} (1)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) to find that the radius of convergence of the power series is $0$--and so it converges only at its center point (at $0$).

Comment: But doesn't that only show it converges at 0?

Comment: That shows that it converges **only** at zero. The radius of convergence is $$1/\limsup\sqrt[n]{n^n}=0.$$